# Loading in two CSV files and storing them in two separate arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

As the title says, I'm loading (or at least trying to) two CSV files and store them in two separate arrays. What I have so far worked, but it isn't the most elegant, no efficient solution.

The end goal is to read in two CSV files and run comparisons on them both - that's why the separating them is important.

*Note* - I use the `csv-parser` library, but am open to different solutions.

```
const express = require("express");
const parse = require("csv-parser");
const fs = require("fs");

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

var CSVOne = [];
var CSVTwo = [];

fs.createReadStream("public/activity.csv")
  .pipe(parse())
  .on("data", data => CSVOne.push(data))
  .on("end", () => {
    sender = CSVOne.map(d => {
      return {
        email: d.Sender
      };
    });
    fs.createReadStream("public/groups.csv")
      .pipe(parse())
      .on("data", dataTwo => CSVTwo.push(dataTwo))
      .on("end", () => {
        one = CSVTwo.map(d => {
          return {
            clinic: d.one
          };
        });
        console.log(sender);
        console.log(one);
      });
  });

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Server has started");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about elegant, but you could load the files in parallel for better performance. To do something when all CSV files are ready you can use promises or just a simple counter.

The example also shows how you can use objects as return value in your arrow functions without the extra `{ return {...} }`.

Example of loading in parallel using the counter method:

```
const express = require("express");
const parse = require("csv-parser");
const fs = require("fs");

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

var CSVOne = [];
var CSVTwo = [];
var toGo = 2;

fs.createReadStream("public/activity.csv")
  .pipe(parse())
  .on("data", data => CSVOne.push(data))
  .on("end", () => {
    sender = CSVOne.map(d => ({
      email: d.Sender
    }));
    maybeDone();
  });

fs.createReadStream("public/groups.csv")
  .pipe(parse())
  .on("data", dataTwo => CSVTwo.push(dataTwo))
  .on("end", () => {
    one = CSVTwo.map(d => ({
      clinic: d.one
    }));
    maybeDone();
  });

function maybeDone() {
  toGo -= 1;
  if (toGo === 0)
    done();
}

function done() {
  console.log("Both CSV files are ready");
  console.log(CSVOne, CSVTwo);
}

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Server has started");
});
```